# Destructuring arrow fuctions in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm quite new to JS and TS, but I'm learning it right because of the Ionic App Framework. I'm following their official tutorial from the docs and encountered a problem.

I have two files `usePhotoGallery.ts` and `tab2.vue`. In `usePhotoGallery.ts` we define and export a wrapper function for an arrow function `takePhoto()`:

```
export function usePhotoGallery() {

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    const cameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100
    });
  };

  return {
    takePhoto
  };
}
```

In `tab2.vue` we import that function like so:

```
import { usePhotoGallery } from './usePhotoGallery'
```

The tutorial now says to "destructure takePhoto from usePhotoGallery" like so:

```
const { takePhoto } = usePhotoGallery();
```

When doing this I get an error saying:

> [vue-cli-service] TS2339: Property 'takePhoto' does not exist on type
> '() => Promise'.

When I remove the curly braces and write `const takePhoto = usePhotoGallery();` though, everything works fine.

This is the link to the tutorial page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/your-first-app/2-taking-photos

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is something you've not done right.  The signature of `usePhotoGallery()` is not `() => Promise` - that would be the signature of `takePhoto()` which is the result of calling `usePhotoGallery()`. The only way the error would make sense if you've (effectively) done `const { takePhoto } = usePhotoGallery().takePhoto;`

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you very much, I found the error. In `usePhotoGallery( )` I wrote `return takePhoto;` when it should have been `return { takePhoto };`.

But I still don't understand the error, what does it mean? What is `'() => Promise'`?

Comment: The error means that you expected `usePhotoGallery()` to be an object that has `takePhoto` key, while it's a function that returns a promise, i.e. `takePhoto`.